# Two lookup fields django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have to create a API for retrieving a superadmin inside a tenant:

my url is like:

```
 path('tenant/<slug:pk>/superadmin/<slug:superadmin>/', SuperAdminRUDView.as_view(), name='tenant-superadmin'),
```

I success fully listed all super admins.But in order TO create a RUD view, it would have two looup fields:

My view:

```
class SuperAdminRUDView(GetSuperAdminsMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = SuperAdminSerializer
    permission_classes = [CreateSuperAdminPermission]
```

GetSuperAdminsMixin is just a mixin for returning the query set.HOw to manage this multiple lookup field.THe retrieval of superadmin should be based on the id as given by slug:superadmin

```
class GetSuperAdmins(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        users = ElsUser.objects.filter(tenant=self.kwargs['pk'])
        super_admin_users = []
        user_roles = []
        role_names = []
        for user in users:
            role_names = []
            user_roles = RoleHelper(user.id).get_user_default_roles()
            roles = PMRole.objects.filter(id__in=user_roles)
            for role in roles:
                role_names.append(role.short_name)
            if "tenant_system_admin" in role_names:
                super_admin_users.append(user)
        return super_admin_users
```

Comment: how `pk` and `superadmin` are related to the QuerySet?

Comment: pk is to know which tenant ,superadmin is id of the superadmin to be fetched.Im trying to fetch the superadmin with id superadmin which is inside tenant with id pk

Comment: i have updated question with the query set. @JPG

Comment: ok i resolved issue,thanks @JPG

Comment: the issue was with returning users.i was returning list instead of queryset